# How to create graph traversal in dse graph using golang

Tags: go, gremlin, gremlin-server

Is there any other way to connect to gremlin server from console without using :remote.

I am using GOLANG to talk to DSE graph. Datastax doesn't provide driver for golang so i am forced use gremlin server to send gremlin queries (there are few GREMLIN plugins for go-gremlin and gremgo). I can create graph using system.graph('test_graph').create() but i am not finding any way to get g for traversing the graph.

Answer (score 1):

DSE Graph requires you to pass an alias with your request to bind `g` to `test_graph.g` where `test_graph` is the name of your graph. There is already an issue for go-gremlin that explains how to do that: https://github.com/go-gremlin/gremlin/issues/4